# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.DLL' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, oracle, dll

we have an ASP.Net 4.5.2 application using the latest Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll from nuget with Entity Framework 5.

File version: 4.121.1.0

Product version: 4.121.1.20131211

When deployed to production environment (Windows Server 2008 r2 x64) all works fine, until we need distributed transactions.

Oracle documentation states that we need to provide Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll (of same version, for specific platform x64) in order to get distributed transactions working.

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException:  Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. ]

Comment: Could you be a little brief in order to find your actual problem and a little code work will provide a clear picture of your work ! @weedo

Comment: Issue on system where Oracle is not installed is resolved by moving Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll to GAC_32. Make sure that you are using correct version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC.dll .

Comment: But still i am having same problem when i try to do this work on windows server 2008

Comment: Here is the source from where i got my solution : http://esjqr.com/article.php?id=24043

Comment: Well I have resolve the issue.. it took me 3 days to figure out that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable is missing from my computer.. I have installed it .. Restart my IIS .. and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable.

If your server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, install from this page:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632 the with SP1 don't work for this server.

If your server is a Windows Server 2012 x64, install from this page:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

Answer (score 0):

My solution turned out to be stop using TransactionScope, and remove a reference to System.Transactions, then the issue went away.

I could get away with this TransactionScope didn't give me any further performance improvements.

Comment: So how are you handling transactions?

Comment: By using the default transactions that come with Entity Framework

Comment: What if you need to change multiple entities at once? Transactionally of course.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem for several months where our product would have problems in some computers (say 1 out of every 10) when the application used transactions.

I tried John's answer and the problem stopped but later I noticed that the transactions where not working at all anymore, in any of the installations.

Finally I got to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallDistributedTransaction.htm#ODPNT8172), where you can see that the *Oracle.ManagedDataAccessDTC* won't be used in .NET Framework Version 4.5.2 or higher. We were using 4.5, so I upgraded the framework to 4.5.2 in two of the computers with that problem and now they work perfectly.

So to sum up, **upgrading the .Net version to 4.5.2 or higher should solve the problem.**

Comment: This occurs with 4.6.1 too.  Downgrading isn't a good solution since 4.6 contains TLS 1.2 security improvements.